# How to narrow down React Component type in tests

Tags: typescript, unit-testing

Learning Typescript

My fn returns string or React component

```
function format(date: string): ReactElement | string {
  const ISODate = parseISO(date)
  if (isNaN(ISODate.getTime())) {
    return date 
  }
  const timeStr = Intl.DateTimeFormat([], options).format(ISODate)

  return (
    <span>
      {timeStr} <Timezone>{stripTimeZone(timeStr)}</Timezone>
    </span>
  )
}
```

then I have a test that cares about the returned component, not string

```
it("returns locally formatted time and date", () => {
      const time = expected.props.children[0]

      expect(time).toBe("12:42 PM") 
    })
```

and it complains that

```
Property 'props' does not exist on type 'string | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>'.
  Property 'props' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

I can understand props does not exist on string, but not sure how to narrow down React component for the Typescript in tests. Feel like this should be simple but cant really find a way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd narrow this type the same you would in code that is not a test.

```
if (typeof expected !== 'string') {
  const time = expected.props.children[0]
  //...
}
```

But since this is a test, maybe you want to throw if a string is returned, since that would not be expected by your test.

```
if (typeof expected === 'string') throw new Error('ReactElement expected, got string')
const time = expected.props.children[0]
//...
```

Or, since this is a test, you can just assert the type and let your expectations fail if the assertion is wrong.

```
const expected = renderMyComponentHere() as ReactElement
const time = expected.props.children[0]
//...
```